# Laravel 5.7 ajax request 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to insert data using Laravel and Ajax. When I submit the form I get following error: 
**500 (Internal Server Error)**

Here the route:

```
Route::post('/insert-data', 'AjaxController@insertData');
```

The controller:

```
    public function insertData(Request $request) {

 if($request->ajax()) {
        $members= Member::create($request->all());

        return response($request->all());
    }



}
```

jquery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
   });

    $('#submitInsert').on('click',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var data = $(this).parent('form').serialize();
         var url = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');


         $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url : url,
             dataType : 'json',

             success: function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
             }

         });
           });
```

I also put

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

but I am still getting 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: 500 means that something does not right on the server side.. can you check on the Laravel's log (its in `storage/logs/laravel.log`)?

Comment: In the logs everything is fine

Comment: have you enabled debug mode in `.env` or in your config file?

Comment: If does not exists any log at Laravel log file so you should try to restart nginx(or whatever) and php-fpm. After that you should check your php-fpm and web server(nginx etc..) log file.

Comment: Found the issue. I forgot to pass serialized data in th ajax call..

Comment: in your response changue for `return response()->json('members' => $members);`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using this script:

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url : url,
             dataType : 'json',

             data: {
            action: "whatever action you want to happen write it here"
        },
...
```

});